# Message form not displaying properly

Tags: php, html, css, forms, message

I've got a problem that I've spent all day on and it's probably a quick fix that I'm overlooking.  I'm hoping a second set of eyes can pick up on it real quick.

The link below has a message submit form and, for some reason, the browser's not picking up on any of the CSS for it.  It's just displaying all of it out as a jumble of unorganized words with no borders, etc.

http://www.hiredavewaring.com/contact.html
The CSS is located in the subfolder /css/swagger.css

Can anyone help me?

Edit: I can't upload screenshots to this forum yet because I'm too new.  But, I've uploaded a screenshot to this link: http://www.hiredavewaring.com/images/ss/problem.png

Comment: Using Firefox's and Google Chrome's `Inspect Element`, I see that all of the CSS provided is being applied.

Comment: What part of the CSS do you think isn't being applied?

Comment: I ran your css through csslint.net. three parsing errors and buttloads of warnings. you may want to correct the errors first.

Comment: Okay, so it looks like it's only happening in Safari 6.0  When opening in Firefox it is all displaying properly.  I do also know about the CSS errors.  Right now, the css page is a mixture of both the old site and new one, so I haven't had a chance to clean it up yet.  I will do soon though.  Thanks Somekid.

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of the site into your question? Unfortunately I don't have Safari.

Comment: The site won't let me upload photos yet, but I included a link to the screenshot in the edited post.  Thanks pop.

Comment: Is that the page's appearance after trying Andrew's answer? The image provided looks exactly like how I see it in Firefox and Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 open curly braces at line 735 of your CSS file at #webwrapper. That may be preventing everything after that line from taking effect.

Comment: +1 I tested your solution, and it appears like that did the trick for Firefox and Google Chrome. Not sure about Safari though, as I don't have it installed. I think this deserves to be the accepted answer :)

Comment: You rock, Andre.  That did the trick.  It now works on Safari 6.0. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/swagger.css" />
```

To:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/swagger.css" media="screen" />
```

Comment: I styled the submit to move it under the left side of the message box's border, but alas I have tried to remove that and it did nothing to help.  Thanks Andrew but that didn't do the trick.

Comment: When you are wanting to use a stylesheet for a base, for example the entire page you should never include the type, which is really only used for extra CSS stylesheets and always include media="screen".